# does path length affect file access performance?

Tags: filesystems

On popular Windows and Linux filesystems (let's say NTFS and Ext4), does path length (both absolute path length as well as number of folders in the path) have any performance impact (other than data overhead, which I read is at least 4kb per folder) on file access or read/write?

Comment: What research have you done on this topic? Do you think it does have an impact? Why?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349455/does-the-length-of-a-file-name-impact-huge-ntfs-folder-indexes